# Google Maps API v3 JavaScript EVENTS question

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps

In Google Maps API v2, I used the following events to each perform
different tasks.

- loaded
- tilesloaded
- moveend

What is the equivalent of these events in API v3?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html the events now supported are:

> `dragstart`
>   `drag`
>   `dragend`
>   `click`
>   `dblclick`
>   `rightclick`
>   `tilesloaded`
>   `idle`
>   `bounds_changed`
>   `resize`
>   `center_changed`
>   `zoom_changed`
>   `maptypeid_changed`

so `tilesloaded` still exists. `moveend` is now `center_changed`, although maybe not exactly the same, it might meet your needs. and `load`?.... well two out of three ain't bad.